# Eclipse claims I do not have a ListView named R.id.list

Tags: java, android, eclipse, listview

So Eclipse is telling me that my app is crashing due to a RuntimeException: "Your content must have a ListView whos id attribute is android.R.id.list". Here's the thing though. As you can see below, I DO have a ListView with an id of list, despite my wishes to name it something more descriptive. 
This is the activity_events.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#e5e5e5">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/list"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:divider="@null"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp">

        </ListView>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/eventsProgressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Am I going crazy here? I've included everything through the onCreate method, since thats where it crashes, but the debugger and LogCat aren't being any more help that what I've told you so far.
Here is the EventsActivity.java file.

```
package com.barjinx.barjinx;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Random;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.Html;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class EventsActivity extends ListActivity {

public static final int MAX_NUMBER_OF_ITEMS = 100;
public static final String TAG = EventsActivity.class.getSimpleName();
protected JSONObject mBarJinxData;
protected ProgressBar mProgressBar;

private final String KEY_BAR_NAME = "bar name"; //Key for eventual bar name to be plugged into Hashmap to populate list data
private final String KEY_GAME_SIDES = "game sides"; //Key for eventual game teams and their relationship to each other to be plugged into Hashmap to populate list data

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_events);

    mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.eventsProgressBar);
    ListView list = new ListView(this);

    if(isNetworkAvailable()) {
        mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        GetEventsDataTask getEventsDataTask = new GetEventsDataTask();
        getEventsDataTask.execute();    
    }
    else {

        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.network_unavailable , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: can you share the complete stack trace from your console?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing ListView's id to `@+id/android:list`

Answer (score 0):

Try naming it to something else

If it doesn't work check if you have imported the resources of your package.